# Call a method by name

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know how to call a method as a string? For example:

```
case @setting.truck_identification
when "Make"
  t.make
when "VIN"
  t.VIN
when "Model"
  t.model
when "Registration"
  t.registration
```

`.to_sym` does not seem to work.

Comment: This question is legitimate, it's about calling a method given that its name is in a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `.send`:

```
t.send @setting.truck_identification.downcase
```

(`vin` should be downcase for it to work)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send), but you'll need to call it with the correct casing. For example:

```
[1,2,3].send('length')
=> 3
```

**Edit**: Additionally, though I would hesitate recommend it because it seems like bad practice that will lead to unexpected bugs, you can deal with different casing by searching through a list of methods that the object supports.

```
method = [1,2,3].methods.grep(/LENGth/i).first
[1,2,3].send(method) if method
=> 3
```

We grep through all methods using a case-insensitive regex, and then send the first returned symbol to the object if any was found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) method to pass the method name as string.
For example:

```
t.send(@setting.truck_identification)
```

You might need to normalize the truck_identification with [`String#downcase`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-downcase) method.

Answer (score 1):

Grepping through the methods isn't the cleanest way to do it.  Just use `#respond_to?()`

```
method = @setting.truck_identification.downcase
if t.respond_to?(method)
    t.send(method)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for a cleaner method. Really appreciated that